# MVC3 - Without saving file to server, output for user download

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, epplus

I have been up the wall and back again with this. The idea is that when a user clicks a link on a page, the controller method will prepare the data, save it to a memory stream and then serve the file to the user. This is my current code:

```
public ActionResult Export(int id1, int id2)
{
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test1");

        //Populate worksheet with data...

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        excelPackage.SaveAs(stream);

        stream.Position = 0;

        return File(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "myfilename.xlsx");
    }
}
```

My issue is that when this button is clicked, the user is not prompted to grab the file. I have stepped through the method and nothing seems off, but I am reasonably new to MVC and may be missing something.

Any assistance would be welcome.

**--EDIT--**

I should mention that for the button I am handling the click in a jquery.click function, and I am reaching the above method through AJAX. Would this be an issue in returning a file?

```
     $(".export").click(function () {
     var ID1 = '<%: Model.ID1%>';
     var ID2= '<%: ViewData["ID2"] %>';

     $.ajax({
         url: '<%= Url.Action("Export", "Export") %>',
         type: "GET",
         data: { id1: ID1, id2: ID2},
         async: false,
         success: function () {

         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Yes, AJAX is the problem here. It's designed to take what comes from the server and put it into a variable for processing/evaluation. If you want the user to interact with the response directly (eg download)  then you need to load the page as if the user typed in the url (see @Artiom's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try next:

```
 $(".export").click(function () {
     var ID1 = '<%: Model.ID1%>';
     var ID2= '<%: ViewData["ID2"] %>';

     var url = '<%= Url.Action("Export", "Export") %>?id1'+ ID1+'$id2'+ID2; // format your url
     window.location=url;
}
```

Not sure about url formatting but you got the point. This worked for me. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is actually pretty much exactly what I did in the end to fix my issue.